# Erro apresentado no vscode ao tentar executar um código em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Pessoa, estou tentando executar alguns scripts em `Python`, porém no `terminal` do `vscode` está sendo mostrando o seguinte erro:

`bash syntax error near unexpected token ('`

Este erro está acontecendo somente no terminal integrado do `vscode`, já reinstalei o programa para verificar se este era o problema.

Estou utilizando um `Linux Mint 19.1 - "Tessa"` com `python 3.7.2`.

Acredito que este, não está relacionada à código, já que um simples `print("Hello World")` apresenta o mesmo erro.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Isso ai tem haver com o Env. Path, conserta isso que vai dar certo

Answer (score 1):

esse tipo de erro acontece quando o sistema operacional está tentando executar diretamente um arquivo de Python, mas não tem um indicador de que ele é um arquivo Python. Em Unix e Linux, ao contrário do Windows, a extensão do arquivo (.py para Python, mas também qualquer outra) - é apenas perfumaria. O sistema operacional olha os primeiros bytes do arquivo para entender que tipo de arquivo é, e no caso de arquivos de script, chamar o interpretador correto.

Resumindo, ponha a lina abaixo como *primeira* linha do seu script Python:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
```

Pronto, isso indica ao sistema operacional que ele deve usar o programa "env" para descobrir qual é o programa correto, no ambiente atual, para executar um script em python3 .

Isso vai arrumar o seu erro específico, mas pode ser que ainda haja outro erro de configuração no seu vscode - ele deveria saber, independente do sistema operacional, que o seu script é em Python , e chamar o interpretador apropriado (não sei dizer se o vscode olha a extensão do arquivo ou o que ele faz). O erro que você colocou é mais comum quando vai se executar um programa em Python direto do terminal.

Comment: Quando o arquivo não possui extensão e também o _shebang_ (`#!...`) que o identifique seu tipo o Bash assume que é o arquivo é dele e este tipo de erro costuma acontecer.